# How to make ajax call in sharepoint 2013

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I am writing a custom web part in sharepoint 2013. I need to make a ajax call. How I am trying
......

In my `CafeteriaWebPart.ascx`, I wrote

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CafeteriaWebPart.ascx.cs" Inherits="RobiCafeteria.CafeteriaWebPart.CafeteriaWebPart" %>

<div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(

        function () {
            alert('Yes');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CafeteriaWebPart.ascx.cs/GetCafeteriaList",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: {},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
        );
</script>
</div>
```

And In my CafeteriaWebPart.ascx.cs, I wrote

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.Services;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;



namespace RobiCafeteria.CafeteriaWebPart
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public partial class CafeteriaWebPart : WebPart
    {
        // Uncomment the following SecurityPermission attribute only when doing Performance Profiling on a farm solution
        // using the Instrumentation method, and then remove the SecurityPermission attribute when the code is ready
        // for production. Because the SecurityPermission attribute bypasses the security check for callers of
        // your constructor, it's not recommended for production purposes.
        // [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, UnmanagedCode = true)]
        public CafeteriaWebPart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public List<CafeteriaModel> GetCafeteriaList()
        {
            var spCafeteriaList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Cafeteria"];

            return (from SPItem item in spCafeteriaList.Items
                    select new CafeteriaModel
                               {
                                   DayName = item["Day Name"].ToString(), MenuItem = item["Menu Item"].ToString()
                               }).ToList();
        }

    }

    public class CafeteriaModel
    {
        public string DayName { get; set; }
        public string MenuItem { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am getting following error

```
POST http://srv-sptest:31618/SitePages/CafeteriaWebPart.ascx.cs/GetCafeteriaList 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Comment: I have the same problem, and the solutions of below are not useful for my. you  Resolved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be the URL of your page followed by the name of the method you want to call. For example:

```
url: "home.aspx/GetCafeteriaList",
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define web method in aspx page instead of ascx. It is not working in user control.

you need to set url as page.aspx/YourMethod.